# How to make a slick slider stops exactly where the touch leaves the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

In this example we have three slides being shown, that's how slick is set to work in this case, but every time I pass it, it doesn't matter where I stop the touch, it goes back to three. But I want it to stop moving when the touch leaves the screen, so if the touch stops when there are like `half-img one-img one-img half-img` I want it to be like that and not get back to `one one one`.

Here the example I mentioned:
https://codepen.io/vilcu/pen/ZQwdGQ

Is that possible to do that?

P.s I tried to insert the snippet here, but I couldn't make slick work in here.